# Having problems getting a macro formula to work

Tags: vba

Trying to reformat an improperly formatted date in a table range so i can sort by dates. I am running into a run-time error '13', type mismatch, with the "Range("B" & y).value" line of code.

I know the formula works because I have tried it in the actual table and I have another formula in the table that is similar and working. I have tried a couple of versions of this formula that work in the actual table, but still get the run-time error, type mismatch, when i run it as a macro

```
'Purchase Date Formula
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim LastRowUsed As Integer

 LastRowUsed = Worksheets("AFOR").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 For y = 2 To LastRowUsed

 Range("B" & y).Value = " =MID([@[purchase-date]],6,2)&" / "&MID([@[purchase-date]],9,2)&" / "&LEFT([@[purchase-date]],4)"

 Next y
```

PurchaseDate
01/24/2019

purchase-date

2019-01-24T13:32:18+00:00

Trying to get the top result (PurchaseDate) from the data on bottom (purchase-date).

Comment: Its how you're formatting your formula that is being inserted into the range value.  The `/` in your formula are outside of the `"s` and its trying to divide a text string by a text string.  You need to properly block off the formula within quotes.  What is your formula "exactly" as you enter it into a cell in excel?  As a side note you can also use .Formula to set the formula for the cell.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out. It works now. I don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with addressing like *[@[Purchase-Date]]* but in my trials it produced an error 2015. Therefore I prefer a more conventional approach in which you might simply read the date and write it to the cell where you want it. For good measure I added a line of code to format it the way you might prefer. Please try.

```
Private Sub DateFromText()

    Dim R As Long
    Dim LastUsedRow As Long
    Dim Tmp As Variant

    With Worksheets("AFOR")
        LastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For R = 2 To LastUsedRow
            Tmp = Left(.Cells(R, "C").Value, 10)
            If IsDate(Tmp) Then
                With .Cells(R, "B")
                    .Value = CDate(Tmp)
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                End With
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The addressing is from a table column. It will auto-format that way when you click the cell. You can change to a regular cell address, but I tend to like it this way. Thank you for the suggestion. I will try it out to see if it works for me. You can't ever know too many ways to solve a problem! Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You may have missed my point. If addressing like [@[Purchase-date]] produces an error in the code which sets the formula you wouldn't know about it unless you test for that specific error in that particular line of code. As you point out, there are many advantages that come with tables, including addressing shortcuts. The disadvantage is that you always have two ways of addressing a cell, a row, a column and a range - either in the sheet or in the table. Your original code mixes the methods. It's easy to lose track. Once you determine the last sheet row relevance of the last table row is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Saw in the comments that you figured it out, but in case someone else has this kind of problem, this addreses three issues:

1- The value in the range object may be replaced with the formula property

2- The initial space at the formula should be avoided

3- The use of quotation marks inside a vba defined formula

```
'Purchase Date Formula
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim LastRowUsed As Integer

 LastRowUsed = Worksheets("AFOR").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
 For y = 2 To LastRowUsed

    Range("B" & y).Formula = "=MID([@[purchase-date]],6,2)&"" / ""&MID([@[purchase-date]],9,2)&"" / ""&LEFT([@[purchase-date]],4)"

 Next y
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I did figure it out and had not gotten back to reply. The error was specifically coming from the &"/"& section of code. I forgot to use double quotes. I also changed to .formula for the range object. Thanks again for responding!